# Laptop Fan Spins For One Second And Stops - No Bootup

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, boot

Acer Aspire 6530 series, Model ZK3, Windows XP

PC Fan Spins For One Second And Stops - No Bootup

When I push the power button it flashes once, then the fan spins for a second, and then everything goes off.

Please advise.

Comment: More info may assist in obtaining an answer.  Make, Model, OS and any recent changes perhaps.

Comment: Make Acer Aspire 6530 series, Model ZK3, win xp and when I push the power button its flash once then fan spin for a second and then everthing goes off.

Comment: @Syed, edit you original question and add all the details.  In the meantime, pull the battery, unplug the laptop and let it sit for a while.  Then try again with just the power cord

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did it already but nothing changed.

Comment: @SyedArifAli, you might want to start accepting some answers, which would probbly encourage more people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly a hardware failure. Probably a problem with the motherboard. You could get your laptop repaired or replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer doesn't beep, it's 9 out of 10 times a motherboard issue. If the computer turns itself off right after you turn it on, it could be a power supply issue, or the CPU overheating (separating the heat sink can rise the CPU temperature above security threshold in a matter of seconds on some CPU models).

You don't seem to have the knowledge to fix this yourself, so I recommend you simply take it to a technician.

Comment: It wouldn't be the CPU overheating in one ten seconds.

Comment: I've seen a computer turn off in *less* than 10 seconds due to overheating. One side of the heat sink support had broken, and the sink had lost all contact to the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has been occurred few months ago with me on my `Acer Extensa 4620.` I thought its a Motherboard problem but it was not, after checking by mechanic it was some kind of circuit (actually I forgot the name of that) that was dead.
Its not necessary in this case it could be a problem of motherboard or a power supply wire or any circuit may  raise the cause to not to boot it up. So you have to handover it to mechanic to check out the real problem.

Comment: Please try to remember the circuit name, that you forgot it, the problem can be fixed by the technician.

Comment: I tried it buddy but couldn't remembered it........but I think technician called it `main chip`.